# Resize images for timelapse before editing or at export of finished video?

Tags: time-lapse

I'm creating a timelapse video which contains around 200,000 pictures.
Before cutting them together i will do some batch color correction with Gimp. Later in the video editing stage (probably using Premiere) I dont plan to change the images but merely cutting them together.

The current image size is 4000x3000 pixels. The final video will be in 1440x1080 pixels. 
Should i do the resizing combined with the color correction in gimp or when I export the file from my video editing software?

Does it make any difference?

Answer (score 1):

This question has some time, but I would like to comment.

Efficiency

In my opinion, the first step would be a batch resize and crop. Do not overwrite the original, but generate a copy instead. There are several programs to do that, that do not even "open" the file.

The reason is that after this step, you can work with smaller-sized assets and not have to drag a humungous file on the next steps, even the planned color adjustments. That is a common task in video editing, so you will have perfectly capable color correction tools on video software. No need to use Gimp.

Even on normal editing, is common to use a lower resolution proxy when editing.

---

An additional note. 1440x1080 is not a common aspect ratio. Some players or users could be tempted to resize to a more common 1920x1080. So it is better to make that decision yourself.

If you do not want to make that decision yet, In my opinion, is better to resample the photos to 1920x1440px first, and use those to make the video. They are easier to work than the original, and you can choose to crop or not once you see the sequence as a video.

Then you could either crop to FullHD without sacrificing the sharpness, or if you still want that aspect ratio, then resample the video once finished.

Answer (score -1):

If I could suggest, use Photoshop to import a sequence of images (they have to be numbered chronologically). There you can edit the sequence just as you would edit a normal photo. Export it as video and then edit with editor of your choice.

I would resize only in the video editor as it gives you the option to change which way you might crop and so forth.

Answer (score -2):

If I could suggest, You can use Photoshop to import you Pictures, Then Export it as video and then get it edited with editor of your choice which i would Recommend You  to use Prem. pro